# Duvidas Sobre janelas Modais

Tags: javascript, html

Ola...Tenho o seguinte codigo abaixo de duas janelas modais...Sendo que elas são do Bootstrap 5...Gostaria de fazer a seguinte ação! abrir a primeira modal, depois clicar em um botão dentro dela para abrir a segunda modal e quando eu fechar a segunda modal, gostaria de que retornasse para a primeira modal automaticamente, vi exemplos parecido com versões mais antigas do bootstrap...tentei esses mesmos exemplos, mas não funcionaram!

```js
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
  // do something...
  $("#myModal2").modal('show');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Cadastros</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop1" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="staticBackdropLabel">Modal 1</h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Digite algo aqui!
          <input name="nome" id="nome" class="form-control"><br><br><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop2">Abrir Modal2</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop1">
  Launch static backdrop modal
</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop2" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="staticBackdropLabel">Modal 2</h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Nome
          <input name="nome" id="nome" class="form-control"> Email
          <input name="nome" id="nome" class="form-control"> Senha
          <input name="nome" id="nome" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para retornar para a primeira modal automaticamente depois de fechar a segunda modal, você pode usar o evento **hidden.bs.modal** da segunda modal para abrir a primeira modal novamente. Para fazer isso, adicione o seguinte código no final do seu HTML:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  $('#modal2').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $("#modal1").modal('show');
  });
});
</script>
```

Isso irá disparar o evento **hidden.bs.modal** da segunda modal quando ela for fechada e, em seguida, abrir a primeira modal novamente. Certifique-se de incluir este código dentro da tag  na seção  ou antes do fechamento da tag .

O código abaixo é um **exemplo** de como retornar ao primeiro modal quando o segundo modal for fechado no Bootstrap 5.

**Segue um exemplo de código para implementação:**

Ele adiciona um ouvinte de eventos **DOMContentLoaded** para garantir que o documento esteja totalmente carregado. Em seguida, é adicionado um ouvinte de eventos para o evento hidden.bs.modal do segundo modal (**#modal2**). Quando esse evento é disparado, o código chama a função **modal('show')** para exibir novamente o primeiro modal (**#modal1**).

**Segue exemplo:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Dois Modais</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Botão para abrir o primeiro modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal1">
    Abrir Modal 1
  </button>

  <!-- Modal 1 -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal1Label" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal1Label">Modal 1</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Conteúdo do modal 1</p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal2">
            Abrir Modal 2
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal 2 -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="modal2" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal2Label" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal2Label">Modal 2</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Conteúdo do modal 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Script para retornar ao primeiro modal quando o segundo modal for fechado -->
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      $('#modal2').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $("#modal1").modal('show');
      });
    });
  </script>

  <!-- Bootstrap 5 JavaScript Bundle com dependências (popper.js e jquery.js) -->
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-a2yjHM4jnF9f54xUQakjZGaqYs/V1CYvWpoqZzC2/Bw="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Observe que a implementação é adicionada ao final do código HTML. O script captura o evento **hidden.bs.modal** da segunda modal e, em seguida, chama a primeira modal para ser exibida novamente usando o método .**modal('show')**. Certifique-se de incluir este código dentro da tag  na seção  ou antes do fechamento da tag .

Comment: Cara me deu até vontade de chorar, você fez meu dia hoje muito feliz, estou fazendo meu TCC da faculdade e precisava fazer essa ação em dua janelas modais do meu projeto, mas não sabia como, vi muitos exemplos com o bootstrap de versões mais antigas...Agradeço Muito!!! Que DEUS lhe abençoe grandiosamente.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, por favor marque que minha resposta resolveu (: Fico feliz em ajuda-lo! Eu tambem aprendo com os questionamentos e é por isso que gosto de ajudar a comunidade!

Comment: minha duvida agora é onde eu marco sua resposta amigo, como solução do meu problema, caí essa semana de paraquedas no Stack overflow, não conhecia, sou novato aqui na comunidade!

Comment: Achei Obrigadão mesmo cara !

Comment: Na lado esquerdo da minha resposta tem umas setas pra cima e pra baixo, voce pode clicar na seta pra cima dando positivo primeiro, e para marcar com a minha resolveu, tem um V, uma especie de OK, é importante marcar ele pra dar como resolvido, ele deve estar log oa baixo das setas,

Comment: valeeeo! obrigado!!!